# Set Default added library in every project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

Every time I set up a new project, I want to add recyclerview, cardview, volley and some others. How do I set up some libraries to be added by default? With more than 10 libraries you have to use each and every project, not a big or not small but all projects

Comment: Sorry, but there is no built-in option for this in Android Studio.

Comment: but android is open source some time kind of change setting it I think possible but I dot know how to do that

Comment: It would take you far less time to just copy the desired `implementation` lines from an existing project into the new project. Forking Android Studio to address this feels like you will soon start [shaving a yak](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/YakShavingDefinedIllGetThatDoneAsSoonAsIShaveThisYak.aspx). :-)